# Convert a char to a String

Tags: string, blackberry, java-me, char

I want to convert a char to a String in the following way:

```
char aaa = '\uE001';
```

I want to obtain a string with the value of `"\uE001"` so I can use `substring(2)` to obtain only `"E001"`. Is that possible? Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the character itself is a *single character*, U+E001. It has the hex value 0xE001. If you want that value as an integer, just use:

```
int unicodeValue = aaa;
```

You can then convert that integer value to hex in various ways, if you really need to, for example:

```
String hex = Integer.toString(unicodeValue, 16);
```

(That's assuming that overload is available on java-me.)

... or `Integer.toHexString` if that's available but `Integer.toString(int, int)` isn't.

Why do you want this value though? If you could clarify that, we may be able to give you more useful advice.

Comment: How to obtain a string representing this char like this "\uE001" meaning 6 different characters not a single char. I want to use substring and just obtain "E001"

Comment: @FaridFarhat: I've given you code to get "E001" - why is the "\u" part important in that case?

Comment: @FaridFarhat You could use String manipulation tools (substring, concatenation, etc) on the result of what Jon provided. All other answers will boil down to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.toHexString((int)aaa) ;
```

..and no substring() required.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple like that

char aaa = '\uE001';

String s=String.valueOf(aaa);

Answer (score 0):

You can take any integer value and create a hex string from it like this:

```
  String s = Integer.toHexString(num);
```

so Jon Skeet is on the right track. You can:

```
  char aaa = '\uE001';
  int num = aaa;
  String hex = Integer.toHexString(num); //now contains "e001"
```